# Upgrading Facebook API version

Tags: php, facebook, api, version

I have recently received a Facebook developer notification:

> **Graph API v2.1 Upgrade Notice**
>
> foobarapplication has been making recent API calls to Graph API v2.0,
>   which will reach the end of the 2-year deprecation window on Monday,
>   August 8, 2016. Please migrate all calls to v2.1 or higher in order to
>   avoid potential broken experiences.
>
> We recommend using our new Graph API Upgrade Tool to see which of your
>   calls are affected by this change as well as any replacement calls in
>   newer versions. You can also use our changelog to see the full list of
>   changes.

A year ago I have upgraded Facebook for the given PHP application, by extracting the PHP SDK and changing source-code usages. The login review was successful and there were no serious problems since then. However, the app needs to upgrade from Facebook API 2.0 soon. I have an idea as of how to achieve this, but am not sure whether I am correct. Let us consider the following functionalities:

`FacebookRedirectLoginHelper` class:

```
  /**
   * Stores CSRF state and returns a URL to which the user should be sent to
   *   in order to continue the login process with Facebook.  The
   *   provided redirectUrl should invoke the handleRedirect method.
   *
   * @param array $scope List of permissions to request during login
   * @param string $version Optional Graph API version if not default (v2.0)
   * @param boolean $displayAsPopup Indicate if the page will be displayed as a popup
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getLoginUrl($scope = array(), $version = null, $displayAsPopup = false)
  {
    $version = ($version ?: FacebookRequest::GRAPH_API_VERSION);
    $this->state = $this->random(16);
    $this->storeState($this->state);
    $params = array(
      'client_id' => $this->appId,
      'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUrl,
      'state' => $this->state,
      'sdk' => 'php-sdk-' . FacebookRequest::VERSION,
      'scope' => implode(',', $scope)
    );

    if ($displayAsPopup)
    {
      $params['display'] = 'popup';
    }

    return 'https://www.facebook.com/' . $version . '/dialog/oauth?' .
      http_build_query($params, null, '&');
  }

  /**
   * Returns a URL to which the user should be sent to re-request permissions.
   *
   * @param array $scope List of permissions to re-request
   * @param string $version Optional Graph API version if not default (v2.0)
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getReRequestUrl($scope = array(), $version = null)
  {
    $version = ($version ?: FacebookRequest::GRAPH_API_VERSION);
    $this->state = $this->random(16);
    $this->storeState($this->state);
    $params = array(
      'client_id' => $this->appId,
      'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUrl,
      'state' => $this->state,
      'sdk' => 'php-sdk-' . FacebookRequest::VERSION,
      'auth_type' => 'rerequest',
      'scope' => implode(',', $scope)
    );
    return 'https://www.facebook.com/' . $version . '/dialog/oauth?' .
      http_build_query($params, null, '&');
  }
```

`FacebookRequest` class:

```
  /**
   * FacebookRequest - Returns a new request using the given session.  optional
   *   parameters hash will be sent with the request.  This object is
   *   immutable.
   *
   * @param FacebookSession $session
   * @param string $method
   * @param string $path
   * @param array|null $parameters
   * @param string|null $version
   * @param string|null $etag
   */
  public function __construct(
    FacebookSession $session, $method, $path, $parameters = null, $version = null, $etag = null
  )
  {
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->method = $method;
    $this->path = $path;
    if ($version) {
      $this->version = $version;
    } else {
      $this->version = static::GRAPH_API_VERSION;
    }
    $this->etag = $etag;

    $params = ($parameters ?: array());
    if ($session
      && !isset($params["access_token"])) {
      $params["access_token"] = $session->getToken();
    }
    if (FacebookSession::useAppSecretProof()
      && !isset($params["appsecret_proof"])) {
      $params["appsecret_proof"] = $this->getAppSecretProof(
        $params["access_token"]
      );
    }
    $this->params = $params;
  }
```

`FacebookCurlHttpClient` class:

```
  /**
   * Detect versions of Curl which report incorrect header lengths when
   * using Proxies.
   *
   * @return boolean
   */
  private static function needsCurlProxyFix()
  {
    $ver = self::$facebookCurl->version();
    $version = $ver['version_number'];

    return $version < self::CURL_PROXY_QUIRK_VER;
  }
```

My idea is as follows:

- `getLoginUrl` is called from the application; a version of 2.6. should be specified from now on
- I do not really use `getReRequestUrl`, so I will not make changes in the code for it
- `FacebookRequest` will be instantiated with a `$version` of 2.6
- `needsCurlProxyFix` will be left as it is

Basically, I will use the PHP lib released in 2014, but with specifying $version at calls. Is my approach feasible, or should I use a new client-side library?

Comment: i am facing same problem did you get any soution by which we can upgrade facebook graph api 2.1 to 2.6 php Thanks

Comment: @usama, that turned out to be a non-issue for me, since my app was already compatible and all tests were successful. Check out the Facebook API Upgrade Tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/241490879195373
There you will see what needs to be changed

Comment: i have tried it shows me this message 
Your app hasn't made enough calls to the Graph API to show any info, or there are no changes for the methods you selected between v2.3 and v2.7.
Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong here.?

Comment: @usama, check out the change log. See all elements and compare your API usage to them: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: Thanks @Lajos can you please also tell me .In my app dashboard i see API Version 2.1 do you know how can i upgrade my Facebook App version to 2.7...?

Comment: @usama, in the app dashboard the needed changes are documented, but as a first step I would recommend that you should fix the issues you have with version 2.1. If you fix those issues, your app should work impeccably and you win many months to resolve your shortcommings compared to version 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As things turned out, my version was up to date and I did not need to do any changes for Facebook's upgrade to version 2.1. except changing the version name used.